# How to add custom http header attribute and value by signed in user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, model-view-controller, http-headers

I'm trying to create an API Management/Broker tool that defines the outgoing URL by HTTP Headers. So for example:

1. User 1 has logged in to the webpage
2. Custom HTTP header is set to (User: 1)
3. Webpage requests API call
4. API Management receives this call and determines outgoing URL by HTTP header(User: 1)

Is this possible or is there a better and effective way? I've created 2 test API's and a front-end with registration and sign in the form now. I'm stuck on adding a custom HTTP header defined by logged in user now.

Hope someone can help and provide me with an approach or example code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use asp.net core Identity. It would maintain your user session information for easy access and storage, as well as providing you with easy security features and authorization for each page according to user permissions. Not only this, but it also provides an easy way to do third party authentication.

> ASP.NET Core Identity is a membership system that adds login
>   functionality to ASP.NET Core apps. Users can create an account with
>   the login information stored in Identity or they can use an external
>   login provider. Supported external login providers include Facebook,
>   Google, Microsoft Account, and Twitter.

[Here is the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

And

[Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97/sourcecode?fileId=147300&pathId=1753673258) is Downloadable tutorial project with it all already implemented for reference.